# UITapGestureRecognizer with UIImageView in Table View Cell not working Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my Table View Controller I'm requesting data from my backend. Then adding the data to an array with a view model for each row from the request.

```swift
let getNotifications = GETNotificationsByUserID(user_id: user_id)
getNotifications.getNotifications { notifications in
    self.notifications = notifications.map { notification in
    let ret = NotificationViewModel()
    ret.mainNotification = notification
    return ret
}
```

```swift
class NotificationViewModel {
    var mainNotification: Notifications? {}
}

struct Notifications: Codable {
    var supporter_picture:String?
}
```

In the same table view controller, I'm then adding each item from the array to a variable in my table view cell.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! NotificationCell
    cell.user_image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let item = self.notifications[indexPath.item]
    cell.viewModel = item
    return cell
}
```

Downloading the image from the data from my table view cell variable and setting my UIImageView image.

UITableViewCell

```swift
class NotificationCell: UITableViewCell {
    var viewModel: NotificationViewModel? {
        didSet {
            if let item = viewModel {
                self.username.text = item.mainNotification?.supporter_username
                item.supporterImageDownloader = DownloadImage()
                item.supporterImageDownloader?.imageDidSet = { [weak self] image in
                    self?.user_image.image = image
                }
                if let picture = item.mainNotification?.supporter_picture {
                    item.supporterImageDownloader?.downloadImage(urlString: picture)
                } else {
                    self.user_image.image = UIImage(named: "profile-placeholder-user")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The UIImageView is created from a lazy closure variable. The lazy closure variable also holds a UITapGestureRecognizer.

UITableViewCell

```swift
lazy var user_image: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    gesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(userImageClicked(_:)))
    gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    image.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return image
}()
   
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addSubview(user_image)
    user_imageContraints()
}
    
func user_imageContraints() {
    user_image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    user_image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    user_image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    user_image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    user_image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
}

@objc func userImageClicked(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("image clicked")
}
```

For some reason when my UIImageView is clicked it doesn't do anything.

Comment: How you add the imageView to view ???

Comment: It's in a table view cell. `addSubview(user_image)` in my init

Comment: show relevant code ? constraints ?

Comment: cell.user_image.userInteractionEnabled = true,  is it about ?

Comment: @sekoyaz that didn't work

Comment: @Sh_Khan check out my new edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
addSubview(user_image)
```

Change it to:

```
contentView.addSubview(user_image)
```

You must never add any views directly to a cell — only to its `contentView`.

Comment: This worked. I had to change some constraints to point to my contentView and add my sub views to my contentView as well. Thanks